# Getting an error in python setup.py install

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to install keras using `python setup.py install` but I am getting an error like this:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File `setup.py`, line 1, in 
    `from setuptools import setup`
ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install setuptools for your system / distro / python version.

https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#install-pip-setuptools-and-wheel